# Given N events, each with probability P, what's the probability of M or more events?

Tags: probability

This is a homework question, and since I want to understand the theory behind it rather than just have the answer, I'm modifying it slightly.

> There are 35 people, all eating from a (large) cookie jar. Each person has the probability of `0.2` that his/her hand is in the cookie jar at any given time, independent of the other persons. What is the probability that 16 or more of them have their hands in the cookie jar all at the same time?

My attempted solution was to sum the probabilities of the 20 different possible events: (19 hands out of the jar * 16 hands in the jar) + (18 hands out of the jar * 17 hands in the jar) + (17 hands out of the jar * 18 hands in the jar) + ...

Which I translated to this equation:

$ \sum\limits_{n = 16}^{35} (1 - 0.2)^{35 - n} (0.2)^{n} $

This gave the result of $ 1.2593 \times 10^{-13} $, which I'm not convinced is correct, primarily because if I change `n` from 16 to 0, I get 0.000540864 when I thought I should get 1 (which very well may be flawed thinking).

What is the proper way to solve these types of problems?

Also, if there are some particular keywords I should be googling, please include those. My searching efforts have been fruitless, probably because I don't know what keywords are relevant here.

Comment: The approach is quite right. You want to include binomial coefficients, though.

Comment: @Eckhard: Ah, that makes sense, I completely forgot about that! Now my numbers are looking right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With thanks to @Eckhard, the problem with my solution was that I wasn't including the binomial coefficients, and thus my formula should have been:

$ \sum\limits_{n = 16}^{35} { 35 \choose n } (1 - 0.2)^{35 - n} (0.2)^{n} $